# Cannot add attachment to mail using flask mail python

Tags: python, email, flask, smtp, flask-mail

I am using flask mail to send mail through SMTP. Mail is working but attachment is not added to mail. I am storing the file path in db and later fetching the file path and attaching the file.
Below is my code

```
msg = Message(
                    subject=mail_data['subject'],
                    recipients=mail_data['to'], 
                    body=mail_data['content'], 
                    sender=mail_data['fromEmail'], 
                    cc=mail_data['cc'], 
                    bcc=mail_data['bcc'], 
                    html=None, 
                    reply_to=None, 
                    date=None, 
                    charset=None, 
                    extra_headers=None,
                    mail_options=None,
                    rcpt_options=None
                    
                )
                for files in mail_data['attachment']:
                    msg.attach(files,mimetypes.guess_type(files))

                mail.send(msg)
```

What is the format to send the attachment. The attachment is dynamic , can be any type of files.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using the below code

```
for files in mail_data['attachment']:
                    mime = magic.from_file(files, mime=True)
                    with open(files,'rb') as f:
                        msg.attach(filename=files, content_type=mime, data=f.read(), disposition=None, headers=None)
```